# Is there An Efficient way of combining two collections?

Tags: c#, loops, nested-loops

I have classes as follows:

```
public class Root
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string PlayerName{get;set;}      
}

public class Scores:Root
{
  public int GameT{get;set;}
  public int GameZ{get;set;}
}

public class Experience:Root
{
  public int ExT{get;set;}
  public int ExZ{get;set;}
}

public class Total:Root
{
   public int TotalT{get;set;}
   public int TotalZ{get;set}
}
```

TotalT and TotalZ are got from adding GameT, ExT and GameZ, ExZ respectively. I have an observable collection of scores and Experience from which I want to create another collection of Total, here is what I have done so far:

```
public ObservableCollection<Total> GetTotal(ObservableCollection<Scores>    scores,ObservableCollection<Experience> experiences)
{
var tc= new ObservableCollection<Total>();
foreach(var scr in scores)
{
  foreach(var exp in experiences)
  {

    if(scr.Id==exp.Id)
    {
     var tt= new Total{
       Id=scr.Id,
       Name=scr.PlayerName,
       TotalT=scr.GameT+exp.Ext,
       TotalZ=scr.GameZ+exp.Exz
       };
     tc.Add(tt);
    }
  }
 }
 return tc;
}
```

It works but it is too slow, especially when the records begin to hit hundreds. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think your current code would even compile - `tt.Id=scr.Id should be just `Id=scr.Id` - the LHS of the `=` in an object initializer can't contain a `.`

Comment: If experience is always tied directly to a given game, why have the two as separate collections? Why not a single collection of games, each with two properties - score and experience?

Comment: Maybe it's duplicated, but I feel that this issue had another solution rather than using `join` (I was about to push the post button when it got closed...)

Comment: @JonSkeet corrected the compile error.

Comment: It would also be useful to know how many scores we're talking about, how many experiences, and how slow is "too slow". I wouldn't expect the long way to be a problem with just "hundreds" of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want a LINQ inner join:

```
var query = from score in scores
            join exp in experiences on score.Id equals exp.Id
            select new Total {
                Id = score.Id,
                Name = score.PlayerName,
                TotalT = score.GameT + exp.Ext,
                TotalZ = score.GameZ + exp.Exz
            };
return new ObservableCollection<Total>(query);
```

That will be more efficient by iterating over all the experiences to start with, collecting them by ID, then iterating over the scores, matching each score with the collection of associated experiences. Basically it turns an O(M * N) operation into an O(M + N) operation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm mistaken, but wouldn't be a good idea to observe the observable collections and collect totals in real time and accumulate results somewhere instead of trying to address the issue all at once?

It's all about implementing observer/observable pattern. Since you can subscribe to collection changes, you can do stuff whenever the collection change. You can also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `Experience.ExT` and `Experience.ExZ` and subscribe to changes of every property from all objects.

This way, you don't need to work on hundred of objects but you just show what's has been accumulated during some period of time.